# Spark does not recognize new lines, &amp, etc. from String

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I'm trying to process text data (Twitter tweets) with PySpark. Emojis and special characters are being red correctly but "\n", "&amp" appear to be escaped. Spark does not recognize them. Probably others too. One example tweet in my Spark DF would look like this:

- "Hello everyone\n\nHow is it going?  Take care &amp; enjoy"

I would like Spark to read them correctly. The files are stored as parquet and I'm reading them like this:

```
tweets = spark.read.format('parquet')\
.option('header', 'True')\
.option('encoding', 'utf-8')\
.load(path)
```

Below are some sample input data, which I took from the original JSONL files (I stored the data as parquet later).

- "full_text": "RT @OurWarOnCancer: Where is our FEDERAL vaccination
  education campaign for HPV?! Where is our FEDERAL #lungcancer
  screening program?! (and\u2026"
- "full_text": "\u2b55\ufe0f#HPV is the most important cause of
  #CervicalCancer But it doesn't just cause cervical cancer (see the figure\ud83d\udc47) \n\u2b55\ufe0fThat means they can be PREVENTED"

Reading directly from JSONL files results in the same recognizing problems.

```
tweets = spark.read.\
.option('encoding', 'utf-8')\
.json(path)
```

How can Spark recognize them correctly? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below code might be helpful to solve your problem,

Input taken:

```
"Hello everyone\n\nHow is it going?  Take care &amp; enjoy"

"full_text": "RT @OurWarOnCancer: Where is our FEDERAL vaccination education campaign for HPV?! Where is our FEDERAL #lungcancer screening program?! (and\u2026 &amp;"
"full_text": "\u2b55\ufe0f#HPV is the most important cause of #CervicalCancer But it doesn't just cause cervical cancer (see the figure\ud83d\udc47) \n\u2b55\ufe0fThat means they can be PREVENTED @theNCI @NCIprevention @AmericanCancer @cancereu @uicc @IARCWHO @EuropeanCancer @KanserSavascisi @AUTF_DEKANLIK @OncoAlert"
```

code to solve the problem:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df=spark.read.csv("file:///home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/raw-data/input.tweet")

df1=df.withColumn("cleandata",regexp_replace('_c0', '&amp;|\\\\n', ''))
df1.select("cleandata").show(truncate=False)

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|cleandata                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Hello everyoneHow is it going?  Take care & enjoy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
|"full_text": "RT @OurWarOnCancer: Where is our FEDERAL vaccination education campaign for HPV?! Where is our FEDERAL #lungcancer screening program?! (and\u2026 &"                                                                                                                                                           |
|"full_text": "\u2b55\ufe0f#HPV is the most important cause of #CervicalCancer But it doesn't just cause cervical cancer (see the figure\ud83d\udc47) \u2b55\ufe0fThat means they can be PREVENTED @theNCI @NCIprevention @AmericanCancer @cancereu @uicc @IARCWHO @EuropeanCancer @KanserSavascisi @AUTF_DEKANLIK @OncoAlert"|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it is normal that Spark does not recognize "\n" etc. during reading?

Comment: since it is a raw data, spark might not aware of the structure of it. you have to cleanse it and get an insight from it after converting raw to structured data. AFAIK, (escape,quote characters can be recognised and replaced at the time of reading , for new line characters in the raw data still I doubt on spark).

Comment: please upvote & accept the answer if your problem got resolved.

Comment: Accepted yours. Unfortunately I cant upvode because I have a new account